# How to have multiple views in fragment call the same onClick function declared in the fragment class?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, onclick, fragment

I have about 8 different buttons in a fragment, which all should call the same function. I set their `tag` property in xml to call that function. I declared that function in the fragment class, but upon calling it, the app crashes with an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onTaskButtonClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_playpause'`

I found out that I would have to implement that function in the Activity that hosts the fragment. I would however like to avoid that because the Activity will host potentially 5+ fragments and if all fragment functions are implemented in that one Activity it will get way too large for my liking.

**edit**

Basically, I want to avoid this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    btn_playpause.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(view) }
    btn_previous_track.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(view) }
    btn_next_track.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(view) }
    btn_volume_down.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(view) }
    btn_volume_up.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(view) }
    btn_mute.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(view) }
}

fun onTaskButtonClick(view: View) {
    presenter.onTaskButtonPressed(view.tag.toString())
}
```

It would seem easier it seems to just have the buttons point to that function in xml.

Comment: If you are using lambda than you should use it instead of view.


btn_playpause.setOnClickListener { onTaskButtonClick(it) }

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I still have all these repetitive lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vararg.

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setClickListenerOnViews(
        btn_playpause,
        btn_previous_track,
        btn_next_track,
        btn_volume_down,
        btn_volume_up,
        btn_mute
    )
}

private fun setClickListenerOnViews(vararg views: View) {
    views.forEach {
        it.setOnClickListener { presenter.onTaskButtonPressed(it.tag.toString()) }
    }
}
```